# Como pegar o length de um *ngFor?

Tags: angular

Possuo uma propriedade `elemento$` dentro do meu componente, cujo tipo é `Observable<Objeto[]>`. Usei a diretiva `*ngFor` pra acessar os dados individualmente e os mostrar na tela:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let elemento of elemento$ | async">
    <p>{{elemento.mensagem}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ao concretizar a atividade, precisei inserir uma tag que não deve aparecer quando acesso o primeiro elemento do array, o que resolvi assim:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let elemento of elemento$ | async; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="!!i">isto não deve aparecer no primeiro elemento</div>
    <p>{{elemento.mensagem}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ao terminar isso, tive que criar também um campo que não pode ficar visível para o último elemento do laço de repetição:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let elemento of elemento$ | async; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="!!i">isto não deve aparecer no primeiro elemento</div>
    <p>{{elemento.mensagem}}</p>
    <div>isto não deve aparecer no último elemento</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Para resolver isso, usei o seguinte código:

```
<div *ngIf="i != ((elemento$ | async).length - 1)">isto não deve aparecer no último elemento</div>
```

Mas acredito não ser a forma ideal de fazer isso. Há uma forma de fazer isso usando as propriedades da própria diretiva `*ngFor` (ex: `*ngfor="let x of y; let total = length"`)?

Comment: Confuso isso ai hein man!!

Comment: gambi design patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diretiva ngFor possui as variáveis locais abaixo:

- index: number; // retorna o índice do item atual no array.
- first: boolean; // retorna true se o item for o primeiro no array.
- last: boolean; // retorna true se o item for o ultimo no array.
- even: boolean; // retorna true se o índice for um numero par no array.
- odd: boolean; // retorna true se o índice for um numero ímpar no array.

```html
<ul *ngIf="elementos$ | async; let elementos" >
  <li *ngFor="let item of elementos; let first = first; let last = last">
    <div *ngIf="!first">isto não deve aparecer no primeiro elemento</div>
    <p>{{item.mensagem}}</p>
    <div *ngIf="!last">isto não deve aparecer no último elemento</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Referencia

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/